# Facebook login for iOS not returning

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, permissions

I have a custom FB login button in my app that runs this code when pressed:

```
[login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile",@"email",@"user_friends"] fromViewController:vc handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Process error");
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         } else {
             if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
                 // User is logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
                 NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"fields":@"email"};

                 [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:parameters]
                  startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                      NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
                  }];

             }
             NSLog(@"Logged in");
         }

     }];
```

The safari viewcontroller popup appears and then I press OK:
[image]

This then goes to a blank page:
[image]

And when I press 'done' it triggers the `NSLog(@"Cancelled");` and I cannot access the email / profile etc.

Comment: Only check to fb documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#delegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your AppDelegate and implement

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool
{
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

This method is responsible for returning right result and closing Safari Controller. Check also your Info.plist file - Facebook scheme (`fbYOUR_FB_APP_ID`) must be configured in order to login flow work properly.

Please also keep in mind that above method is deprecated. New version is `application:openURL:options:` and if you have that implemented - above won't be called. Because of FacebookSDK still uses old method in `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` you can stick to old one or try to convert new method's params into old one for FB purposes.

Comment: thanks, I was just an idiot - I had this line commented out!